# Is the position coordinate of a pixel the center coordinate of that pixel?

Tags: qgis, image, pixel

Is the position coordinate of a pixel the center coordinate of that pixel?

For example, in an image composed of 4 pixels as shown in the figure below, the coordinate values of 150 and 150 are put in the upper right pixel.
[image]
Are all parts of the pixel equal to 150,150? Or does the center value of the pixel become 150,150?

Comment: it depends, sometimes it is the centre and sometimes the lower left corner and sometimes the upper left corner - the pixel will always have a width and height though

Comment: Since there are multiple ways to reference rasters, you need to provide context in the Question body.

Comment: With the raster sources that QGIS is using the anchor point is either at the top-left corner of the pixel or in the middle. You can find references by searching "pixelisarea" and "pixelispoint". Here is one https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-coverages/issues/92.